# Jquery or JS code to change the GET URL parameters

Tags: jquery, get

I have a page with a check box so that when its checked, it will submit values and parameters via GET, this is how it looks like by default:

**Passing two product SKUs**:

```
http://example.com/product-comparisons/?product-skus=1&product-skus=2
```

**Passing only one product SKUs:**

```
http://example.com/product-comparisons/?product-skus=1
```

OR this:

```
http://example.com/product-comparisons/?product-skus=2
```

What I want to accomplish is to change the GET parameter ONLY when passing two or more products such as this:

```
http://example.com/product-comparisons/?product-skus=1&product-skus=2
```

INTO THIS:

```
http://example.com/product-comparisons/?product-skus=1,2
```

And when there are no checked products but the form is submitted, it will change the URL from:

```
http://example.com/product-comparisons/
```

INTO THIS:

```
http://example.com/product-comparisons/?product-skus=0
```

that is adding 0 to the product-skus query string variable.

I already have a jQuery code that will run when the submit button is clicked:

```
jQuery( document ).ready( function( $ ) {
$('#myform').submit( function() {

    //change the GET URL parameters


 });
```

});

But I'm stuck with the rest of the process. I would like this to happen when submitting the form. I would be glad if someone can provide some sample code to get started. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to offer a suggestion that doesn't directly answer your question, but which will probably solve your problem, and may save you a lot of work and headache in the process.

I assume you want to modify the GET params because your server-side application is only receiving one of the values when many are passed, and you want to split the comma-delimited param to solve your problem.

There's an easier alternative.

Change your checkbox `name` attribute to `product_skus[]`, and when you read it on your server-side app, it will be retrieved as an array.

e.g.:

```
http://example.com/product-comparisons/?product-skus[]=1&product-skus[]=2
```

If you're reading this in PHP:

```
print_r($_GET['product_skus']);`
```

Will give you:

```
Array(0 => '1', 1 => '2')
```

Hope that helps you out!

(PS - You can do this with other server-side languages, too, like Python, and I'm sure most other modern languages. Java and .NET can do it without the [] syntax, so I'm pretty sure you're not using those.)